# How to increment property's value(integer) and update with some restrictions in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a studentSchema in which there are pass property with default value 0 . So I want to increse that value by 1 when user creates new pass.

```
 pass: {
  type: Number,
  default: 0,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand you correctly, you can use mongoose [pre hook](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) in this way:

Assuming you are updating in this way (or similar):

```js
model.update({_id:value},{$set:{yourPasswordField:"newName"}})
```

Then you need:

- First get if exists the value `$set.yourPasswordField` which means you hace updated the question in that query.
- Then, if exists, get the document updated using the same filter
- And last update the desired field.

```js
MongooseModel.pre('update', async function () {
  // get the fields which have been updated.
  const passUpdated = this.getUpdate().$set.yourPasswordField;
  if(passUpdated){
    // Find the object using the filter in your query (i,e: {_id:value} )
    const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getFilter());
    // Then update the value into 1 and save into DB
    docToUpdate.pass = docToUpdate.pass + 1;
    docToUpdate.save()
  }
});
```

Comment: sorry you didn't get it , [https://stackoverflow.com/q/65614871/14863808 ] please follow this link here I describe  it in details